# Finding the dimension of $U=\{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}_3[x]\text{ } |\text{ } p(a) = 0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $U = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}_3[x]\text{ } |\text{ } p(a) = 0\}$. How do I find $\dim(U)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\in U,a_i\in\Bbb R$

$p(a)=0\implies a_0+a_1a+a_2a^2+a_3a^3=0$

Substitute for $a_0$ in $p(x)$,

$p(x)=-(a_1a+a_2a^2+a_3a^3)+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3=a_1(x-a)+a_2(x^2-a^2)+a_3(x^3-a^3)$

which is a linear combination of $3$ linearly independent vectors of $\Bbb R_3[x]$, giving the dimension as $3$.